# Bitmap region locked / bitmap in use elsewhere error

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, tesseract, emgucv

I have a program where I perform OCR on selected text lines in an image, I used a for loop and it works well. Only problem is that in for loop each line is processed after the previous one is done which adds up the processing time.

So I tried using a parallel.for statement so that all lines will be processed together(max 5 lines). When there is only 1 line it works and I get no error, but when there are multiple lines, I get the following errors :

```
   System.InvalidOperationException: 'Bitmap region is already locked.'

   OR Bitmap is in use elsewhere
```

Im using EMGU and tesseract class for processing.

This is my code :

```
   private void ocrmethod()
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
                Image<Gray, byte> temp = frame.Convert<Gray, byte>().Clone();
              //  for (int i = 0; i < imgcount; i++)
                 Parallel.For(0, imgcount, i =>
                {      
                        temp.ROI = LineRect[i]; // Selected text line region in the image
                        OCR_Class doocr = new OCR_Class();
                        Image<Gray, byte> foundareafilter = temp.Copy();                           
                        
                        bitmap2 = new Bitmap(foundareafilter.ToBitmap<Gray, byte>());                           

                        //OCR SECTION

                        doocr.trainingdatapath(@"./OCRtraindata", "eng");  
                        doocr.ProcessOCR(bitmap2, 1);
                        string result = doocr.result().Replace(" ", "").Replace("  ", ""); 
               // } 
                });           
          });
           
    }
```

I cant figure out how to make the bitmaps available to all process simultaneously. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Changing external variables in a parallel loop leads to their locking.
`bitmap2 = new Bitmap(foundareafilter.ToBitmap<Gray, byte>());`

- You need to make [thread-safe code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices)
- [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying
  Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4 - Stephen Toub](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222)